# Repackage a .pyd file so it can be pushed to a python package repository

Tags: python, setuptools, python-importlib

I have a `module.pyd` from a vendor that i want to push to our internal PyPi and then be able to `pip install module` and then later `import module`.

The `module.pyd` is rather hard to cater to though (and i cant modify it). It requires a number of other dlls in its directory and it can't be renamed, likely due to a `PyInit_module` definition. I tried to put together a structure like this:

```
src/
├─ module/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ module.pyd
│  ├─ other_dll.dll
MANIFEST.IN
setup.cfg
```

Issues arise though if i want to keep all the names the same ("module"). since i want to be able to `pip install module` i assume i need the package to be called "module". I tried using this code in `src/module/__init__.py`

```
import sys
import importlib.util

module_package_spec = importlib.util.find_spec("module")
package_dir = module_package_spec.submodule_search_locations[0]

module_pyd_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module", package_dir + "\\module.pyd")
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(module_pyd_spec)
sys.modules["module"] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

however this gives

```
> module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(module_pyd_spec)
SystemError: initialization of module did not return an extension module
```

which i assume is from the package and module name collision.
If i run

```
import importlib.util

module_pyd_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module", "<PACKAGE_ABSOLUTE_DIR>\\module.pyd")
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(module_pyd_spec)
```

outside of the package, it works.

Another rather undesirable option would be dumping the `.pyd` file along with all dlls in a users `Lib/site-packages`, which when i did it manually did work, but I'm not sure how to make setuptools do that.

What can i try to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

We ended up trying the undesirable option, dumping the pyd and dlls into site packages. It can be achieved with a custom setup.py, something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install
from setuptools.dist import Distribution
import glob
import shutil


class CustomInstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        # run the original install command
        install.run(self)

        # copy the .pyd and .dll files to site-packages
        module_dir = self.install_lib
        shutil.copy('src/dlls/module_.pyd', module_dir)
        for dll in glob.glob("src/dlls/*.dll"):
            shutil.copy(dll, module_dir)


class BinaryDistribution(Distribution):
    """Distribution which always forces a binary package with platform name"""
    def has_ext_modules(self):
        return True


setup(
    name='module_repack',
    version='1.0',
    description="A packaged version of the module",
    packages=find_packages(where="src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    include_package_data=True,
    cmdclass={'install': CustomInstallCommand},
    distclass=BinaryDistribution
)
```

and a slightly different folder structure:

```
src/
├─ dlls/
│  ├─ other_dll.dll
│  ├─ module.pyd
├─ module/
│  ├─ __init__.py
MANIFEST.in
setup.py
```